# Missing categories for Custom Taxonomy and Custom Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm having trouble seeing why categories are not appearing for Knowledge Base and Articles. What's wrong with this code?

```
<?php
// Custom post types

/* faq */
add_action( 'init', 'faq_post_type' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'faq_post_type' ) ) {
function faq_post_type() {

    //Register FAQ Post Type
    register_post_type( 'faq',
        array(
        'description' => __( 'FAQ Articles', 'guerilla' ),
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'FAQ', 'guerilla' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'FAQ', 'guerilla' ),
                'add_new' => __('Add New', 'guerilla'),  
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New FAQ', 'guerilla'),  
                'edit_item' => __('Edit FAQ', 'guerilla'),  
                'new_item' => __('New FAQ', 'guerilla'),  
                'view_item' => __('View FAQ', 'guerilla'),  
                'search_items' => __('Search FAQ', 'guerilla'),  
                'not_found' =>  __('No FAQ found', 'guerilla'),  
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No FAQ found in Trash', 'guerilla')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 7,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faq'),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
        )
    );
}
}

function faq_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array('name' => __( 'Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'guerilla' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name', 'guerilla' ),
                    'menu_name' => __( 'Categories', 'guerilla' ) );

    register_taxonomy(  'faq_category',
                        array( 'faq' ),
                        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
                        'labels' => $labels,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'public' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'faq_category' )));
}

add_action( 'init', 'faq_taxonomy' );

/* Knowledgebase*/
add_action( 'init', 'KnowledgeBase_post_type' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'KnowledgeBase_post_type' ) ) {
function KnowledgeBase_post_type() {


    register_post_type( 'KnowledgeBase',
        array(
        'description' => __( 'KnowledgeBase Articles', 'guerilla' ),
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'KnowledgeBase', 'guerilla' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'KnowledgeBase', 'guerilla' ),
                'add_new' => __('Add New', 'guerilla'),  
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New KnowledgeBase Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'edit_item' => __('Edit KnowledgeBase Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'new_item' => __('New KnowledgeBase Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'view_item' => __('View KnowledgeBase Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'search_items' => __('Search KnowledgeBase Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'not_found' =>  __('No KnowledgeBase Articles found', 'guerilla'),  
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No KnowledgeBase Articles found in Trash', 'guerilla')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'KnowledgeBase'),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
        )
    );
}
}

function KnowledgeBase_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array('name' => __( 'Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'guerilla' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name', 'guerilla' ),
                    'menu_name' => __( 'Categories', 'guerilla' ) );

    register_taxonomy(  'KnowledgeBase_category',
                        array( 'KnowledgeBase' ),
                        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
                        'labels' => $labels,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'public' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'KnowledgeBase_category' )));
}

add_action( 'init', 'KnowledgeBase_taxonomy' );

/* Articles */
add_action( 'init', 'Articles_post_type' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'Articles_post_type' ) ) {
function Articles_post_type() {

    //Register FAQ Post Type
    register_post_type( 'Articles',
        array(
        'description' => __( 'Articles', 'guerilla' ),
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Articles', 'guerilla' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Articles', 'guerilla' ),
                'add_new' => __('Add New', 'guerilla'),  
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'new_item' => __('New Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'view_item' => __('View Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'search_items' => __('Search Articles', 'guerilla'),  
                'not_found' =>  __('No Articles found', 'guerilla'),  
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Articles found in Trash', 'guerilla')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Articles'),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
        )
    );
}
}

function Articles_taxonomy()
{
    $labels = array('name' => __( 'Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'all_items' => __( 'All Categories', 'guerilla' ),
                    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'guerilla' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'update_item' => __( 'Update Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category', 'guerilla' ),
                    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name', 'guerilla' ),
                    'menu_name' => __( 'Categories', 'guerilla' ) );

    register_taxonomy(  'Article_category',
                        array( 'Articles' ),
                        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
                        'labels' => $labels,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'public' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'Article_category' )));
}

add_action( 'init', 'Articles_taxonomy' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Knowledgebase and Articles CPT slugs are capitalized. This is not allowed - [see the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters).

> (string) (required) Post type. (max. 20 characters, can not contain
>   capital letters or spaces)

Change these to all lower case, both in the first parameter of the `register_post_type` and in the second parameter of the `register_taxonomy`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: FAQ is not linked yet i can see the categories for FAQ.

Comment: I've tried the suggested idea and that dont work.

Comment: I've totally revised my answer.

Comment: If my answer is correct please click the tick next to it, so that other people with the same issue can see it is correct.